# Google Drive Export (Google Vault) for Specific User

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-vault-api

Following the [docs](https://developers.google.com/vault/guides/exports), there's an example to export all for a specific OU

```
def create_drive_ou_all_data_export(service, matter_id):
  ou_to_search = 'ou id retrieved from admin sdk'
  drive_query_options = {'includeSharedDrives': True}
  drive_query = {
      'corpus': 'DRIVE',
      'dataScope': 'ALL_DATA',
      'searchMethod': 'ORG_UNIT',
      'orgUnitInfo': {
          'org_unit_id': ou_to_search
      },
      'driveOptions': drive_query_options,
      'startTime': '2017-03-16T00:00:00Z',
      'endTime': '2017-09-23T00:00:00Z',
      'timeZone': 'Etc/GMT+2'
  }
  drive_export_options = {'includeAccessInfo': False}
  wanted_export = {
      'name': 'My first drive ou export',
      'query': drive_query,
      'exportOptions': {
          'driveOptions': drive_export_options
      }
  }
  return service.matters().exports().create(
      matterId=matter_id, body=wanted_export).execute()
```

However, it does not show how to just export for a given user, is this possible? Also, where are all of the different body options for creating an export? The examples do not seem to show all of the parameters available.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to use searchMethod:account
Reference Query: https://developers.google.com/vault/reference/rest/v1/Query
Reference searchmethod: https://developers.google.com/vault/reference/rest/v1/Query#SearchMethod
Reference AccountInfo: https://developers.google.com/vault/reference/rest/v1/Query#AccountInfo

```
drive_query = {
      'corpus': 'DRIVE',
      'dataScope': 'ALL_DATA',
      'searchMethod': 'ACCOUNT', # This is different
      'accountInfo': { # This is different
          'emails': ['email1@company.com', 'email2@company.com', 'email3@company.com']
      },
      'driveOptions': drive_query_options,
      'startTime': '2017-03-16T00:00:00Z',
      'endTime': '2017-09-23T00:00:00Z',
      'timeZone': 'Etc/GMT+2'
  }
```